Cannot run flutterfire configure with subprocess.Popen
Can someone please tell me how to process flutterfire configure with popen without stopping in the middle?
I want to automate the flutterfire configure command with python subprocess.Popen, but it stops at selecting the firebase project.
Popen's argument, cwd, is the address of the file where you want to execute the command.
configure = subprocess.Popen(
  "flutterfire configure",
  shell = True,
  stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
  stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
  stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
  cwd = path
)

run_command_configure = True

while run_command_configure:
  line_configure = configure.stdin.readline().decode().strip()
  print(line_configure)
 
  if "Select" in line_configure: configure.stdin.write("\n".encode())

  if "Which platforms" in line_configure: configure.stdin.write("\n".encode())

  if "Which Android application id" in line_configure:
    #dir is directory name
    dir += ".app\n"
    configure.stdin.write(dir.encode())

  configure.stdin.flush()
  if "Learn" in line_configure: run_command_configure = False

The following log is displayed, but subsequent logs are not displayed and the command stops.

i Found 1 Firebase projects.
? Select a Firebase project to configure your Flutter application with ›
❯ project-b82d2 (project)
<create a new project>

